# Failure of a prop. regarding absolutely continuous measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> **Proposition A:** Let $\left(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu\right)$ be a measure space and $\nu$ a finite measure on the measurable space $\left(X, \mathcal{M}\right)$. Then $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ if and only if for each $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for any set $E\in\mathcal{M}$,
> $$\text{if } \mu(E)<\delta,\text{ then } \nu(E)<\varepsilon.\tag{1}$$

My question is, why is the finiteness of $\nu$ needed? That is, I should be able to find a non-finite measure $\nu$ on a measurable space $\left(X, \mathcal{M}\right)$ with $\nu\ll\mu$ such that $(1)$ fails to hold, even if $\mu$ is finite on the measurable space $\left(X, \mathcal{M}\right)$.

My though was to consider $X:=\mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{M}:=\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$, and letting $\nu$ be the counting measure. As $\nu(X) = +\infty$, $\nu$ is non-finite on the measurable space $\left(X, \mathcal{M}\right)$. Then, let $\mu$ be another measure on the measurable space $\left(X, \mathcal{M}\right)$ for which $\nu\ll\mu$.

This is where I'm at right now. I'd expect a solution would follow by contradiction, but not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thought is good; you just need to specify a measure $\mu$.  Try the "weighted counting measure" for which $\mu(\{n\}) = 2^{-n}$.  You can then easily check that $\nu \ll \mu$, but that as soon as $\epsilon < 1$, there can be no $\delta$ satisfying (1) for all $E$.

Comment: So, I know you said "easily check that $\nu\ll\mu$"; however, I'm having a slight issue showing such. That is, let $E\in\mathcal{M}$ be such that $\mu(E)=0$. I'm not sure how to explicitly write down what $\mu(E)$ is. Probably some summation of $2^{-n}$ for however many elements are in the set $E$?

Comment: @D.Math: Exactly, it is $\mu(E) = \sum_{n \in E} 2^{-n}$.  Hence if $\mu(E) = 0$ it must be that $E = \emptyset$. You can see this even more trivially just by noting that if $n \in E$ then $\mu(E) \ge \mu(\{n\}) = 2^{-n} > 0$.

Comment: Ah! So, since $\nu$ is a measure it must be that $\nu(E) = \nu(\emptyset)=0$-- which concludes that $\nu\ll\mu$?

Comment: @D.Math: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks! For the second part, as soon as $\epsilon<1$, does this make $E=\emptyset$?

Comment: @D.Math: Yes, it means the only $E$ that can satisfy $\nu(E) < \epsilon$ is $E = \emptyset$.  So now you have to find a nonempty $E$ with $\mu(E) < \delta$ and you will have shown that (1) fails.

Comment: I've though about it, but I'm not getting anywhere. What nonempty set should $E$ be to satisfy $\mu(E)<\delta$?

Comment: @D.Math: You can just think about a singleton of the form $E = \{n\}$ for some $n$ which we will choose.  Then what would $\mu(E)$ be?

Comment: Then, $\mu(E)=2^{-n}$, but I don't see how that ensures that $\mu(E)<\delta$?

Comment: Just **choose** an $n$ with $2^{-n} < \delta$.  This is certainly possible since $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{-n} = 0$.  Remember your set $E$ is allowed to depend on $\delta$ (look carefully at the order of quantifiers in what you are trying to prove).

Comment: Ah, so we don't actually specify a $n$ but rather say something like, "let $n$ be such that $2^{-n}<\delta$". Then define the nonempty set $E$ to be $E:=\{n\}$?

Comment: @D.Math: Right, that is the idea.  If you really want, you can "specify" a $n$, say $n = \lceil - \log_2 \delta \rceil + 1$, but it's not necessary.  We know that there exists an integer $n$ with $2^{-n} < \delta$ and that suffices.

Comment: Hopefully you will see this: I'm trying to show that this so-called *weighted counting measure* $\mu$ is, in fact, a measure on the measurable space $\left(X,\mathcal{M}\right)$. I can show everything expect that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$. I'm begging to question if we need to define separately that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ since I'm not sure how you'd otherwise conclude that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.

Comment: @D.Math: Right, as I said, one should more properly define $\mu(E) = \sum_{n \in E} 2^{-n}$ (\*) for all sets $E \subset \mathbb{N}$.  There's a convention that any sum over the empty set is taken to be 0, so it does satisfy $\mu(\emptyset) =0$.  My initial description by just saying $\mu(\{n\}) = 2^{-n}$ is a common shorthand; you can show that the measure defined by (\*) is the unique countably additive measure on $\mathcal{M} = \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ satisfying $\mu(\{n\}) = 2^{-n}$ for every $n$.

Comment: Ah okay I see. Could you tell me where you found this measure from? I follow roydens text and don't see it anywhere.

Comment: I don't have any books handy to check, but it's sort of "common knowledge" that measures on $\mathbb{N}$ can be constructed this way.  More precisely, given any sequence $a_n$ of nonnegative real numbers, there exists a unique countably additive measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{M} = \mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ for which $\mu(\{n\}) = a_n$ for every $n$, and $\mu$ is a finite measure iff $\sum a_n < \infty$.  Many books have something like this as a theorem or exercise.  There's nothing magical about $a_n = 2^{-n}$; it's just a convenient example of a summable sequence.

Comment: I guess now this is "common knowledge" to me now, thanks!